# Put method of Redu-Saga doesn't launch the correspondent Reducer

Tags: javascript, redux, redux-saga

This is my saga (index and specific saga):
Index of saga:

```
    import { all } from 'redux-saga/effects';

    import search from './search';

    export default function* rootSaga() {
        yield all([search]);
    }
```

Specific Saga:

```
    import { put, call, takeLatest } from 'redux-saga/effects';
    import {
        SEARCH_MOVIE_START,
        SEARCH_MOVIE_COMPLETE,
        SEARCH_MOVIE_ERROR,
    } from '../../consts/actionTypes';

    import { apiCall } from '../api';

    export function* searchMovie({ playload }) {
        try {
            console.log('Accion inical');
            const results = yield call(
                apiCall,
                `&s=${playload.movieName}`,
                null,
                null,
                'GET'
            );
            yield put({ type: SEARCH_MOVIE_COMPLETE, results });
        } catch (error) {
            yield put({ type: SEARCH_MOVIE_ERROR, error });
        }
    }

    export default function* search() {
        yield takeLatest(SEARCH_MOVIE_START, searchMovie);
    }
```

As you can see, in this saga is a console.log() and a put() method, but neither console.log() nor put() work, I mean in browser console doesn't appear any messager. Also I use a Redux DevTools and in the actions section only appear SERACH_MOVIE_START, but not appear SEARCH_MOVIE_COMPLETE or SEARCH_MOVIE_ERROR (in the case that my call in my api fail)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/13e9O.png)

My reducer (index and specific reducer):
My index:

```
    import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
    import search from './search';

    const rootReducer = combineReducers({
        search,
    });

    export default rootReducer;
```

My specific reducer

```
    import {
        SEARCH_MOVIE_COMPLETE,
        SEARCH_MOVIE_ERROR,
        SEARCH_MOVIE_START,
    } from '../../consts/actionTypes';

    const initialState = {};

    export default function (state = initialState, action) {
        switch (action.type) {
            case SEARCH_MOVIE_START:
                return { ...state };
            case SEARCH_MOVIE_ERROR:
                console.log(action);
                return { ...state };
            case SEARCH_MOVIE_COMPLETE:
                console.log(action);
                return { si: 'no lo creo', ...state };
            default:
                return { ...state };
        }
    }
```

and store:

```
    import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
    import createSagaMiddleware from 'redux-saga';
    import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension';

    import rootReducer from '../reducers';
    import rootSaga from '../sagas';

    const configureStore = () => {
        const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();
        return {
            ...createStore(
                rootReducer,
                composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleware))
            ),
            runSaga: sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga),
        };
    };

    export default configureStore;
```

Comment: Please console the action and action.type.

export default function (state = initialState, action) {
       // here ----------------

Comment: Try using fork to start the specific saga, e.g.: `yield all([fork(search)]);`

Comment: Thanks everyone, but I'd fixed it add '()' next the function search in my "rootReducer" file